# Copying git local branch between machines?

Tags: git

OK so I'm tracking a remote repo on two machines so both have the master branch.  I also made a local branch on my laptop called development.  Is there a way for me to copy that local branch over to my desktop computer?  I'd use my laptop but for some reason I'm having trouble with gdb and emacs...

Edit: This worked for me

```
git remote add laptop [username]@hostname:/path/to/repo
git fetch laptop
git checkout --track -b development laptop/development
git pull
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's assume that you have both repository on 'desktop' machine and repository on 'laptop' machine set up in such way that you can fetch on 'desktop' from 'laptop' and vice versa (e.g. via SSH, or via `git://` protocol i.e. via git-daemon, or perhaps via simple HTTP).

Both 'desktop' and 'laptop' machine have 'master' branch, and additionally 'laptop' machine has 'development' branch.

Let first set up **remote** shortcut, and **remote-tracking branches** using [git remote](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html):

```
desktop$ git remote add laptop user@laptop:/path/to/repo
```

This would set up remote named 'laptop' and remote-tracking branches: 'laptop/master' (or to be more exact 'refs/remotes/laptop/master') which follows branch 'master' on 'laptop', and 'laptop/development' which follows branch 'development' on 'laptop'.

Then you need to create **local branch** 'development' on 'desktop', which would follow (track) remote-tracking branch 'laptop/development' (as you can't develop on remote-tracking branches):

```
desktop$ git checkout -b development --track laptop/development
```

or just simply (with modern git)

```
desktop$ git checkout --track laptop/development
```

See [git-branch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) manpage for details.

This setup allows to use simply "git pull" when on branch 'development' while on 'desktop', and git would automatically fetch all changes fro repository at 'laptop' into 'laptop/master' and 'laptop/development' remote-tracking branches, and then try to merge 'laptop/development' into 'development' (current branch) -- which would usually result in *fast-forward*, i.e. simply moving 'development' branch.

Then you can create similar setup on 'laptop' (although setting up existing branch 'development' on 'laptop' to track 'desktop/development' might require editing config file directly or via "git config").

Comment: Is not '--track' unnecessary? The docs say that "this behavior is the default when the start point is a remote branch".

Comment: It is probably unnecessary, at least in first case (with explicit '-b' to start new branch), depending on `branch.autosetupmerge` (defaults to true).

Comment: So can someone please explain what one needs to do on 'laptop' to enable reciprocal pulls from 'desktop' to 'laptop'. What config file do one need to edit or how do I use git config to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just git pull the remote branch from your laptop? Git will pull over http, ssh - many protocols. My git syntax is rather rusty, but something like…

Edit: Digging through memory and manuals, you may need to initially add the new remote with

```
git remote add ssh://remotestuff/
```

then you can

```
git checkout --track -b localBranchName remote/remoteBranch
```

to track the branch.

Comment: I get "fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches/forcing

Comment: Rather hoping someone comes along with a better branching answer than this. I do find the git syntax and manuals to be largely inscrutable, which has spawned a huge industry of git "tutorials" that all differ slightly.

Comment: @gct: The "updating paths is incompatible..." error typically means you have local changes in your current branch.  Those changes need to be removed prior to checking out the new repo.  If you need to keep them, you could `git stash` then `git checkout` and finally `git stash apply`.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the repo in a usb stick, plug it in the second laptop/pc, `cd` to the repo and do:

```
git remote add usbstick path/to/repo/in/usbstick
git fetch usbstick
git branch branch_name usbstick/branch_name
```